# Ask for user input file and store it in gui

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to do a project. For it, the gui asks for a file path and file name. Once the user enters it, the file will be moved and be stored on my gui interface. This is by using python

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for asking code from scratch.  You need to try it yourself and post the issue you come across and a [mre].

Comment: "Send it to shrutipatnaik2002@gmail.com" - but first, send some BTC my way, please

Answer (score 1):

What are you really attempting to do? I do not understand your idea. Do you mean to get a file and display the contents? If so, the tkinter filedialog module.

```
from tkinter import filedialog as fidia

filename = fidia.askopenfilename()
fileread = os.open(filename, "rt")
print(os.fileread())
```

As I said, I am not sure about your question.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using Tkinter as GUI module, you should import the library "filedialog" to do something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

class Window: # Your main window's class
    def __init__(root): # window's constructor method
        root.win = Tk() # the declaration of the Tkinter object
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(root.win) # The variable holding the string of the file opened in the dialog
        root.win.mainloop() # Calling the tkinter method that starts the window

myWin = Window()
```

By the way: I think your question is legit, but you should try to find out more about this on the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#module-tkinter.filedialog)

Next time take some time to read the docs, you would have found the answer in 10 minutes, **just be patient!** ;)